# Program that reads python code aloud and pauses at right times?

Tags: python

There's already read text aloud programs but they don't really understand python indentation and won't read it in a way with pauses that reflect things like indentation and creating variables. The read aloud program might blitz through a few lines then go slowly through some when in real life you would read code aloud differently.

For example, - is not read as minus. * is not read as "times" 
/ is read as slash as opposed to divided by

Comment: - is not read as minus? What else is it in Python?

Comment: If you know how you want it being read, why not perform a simple search/replace operation before?

Comment: I could but its a considerable amount of work to do all the edits if you think about it. Some programs might have large blocks of #### some programs might have - in comments, and how would you replace parenthesis for example? Would you really put "left parenthesis" for every ( ? I'm wondering if someone has made some sort of slick program that can read code aloud like a person would. Imagine I'm blind. Not that blind people code very often.

Comment: Good point. How do you want parenthesis be read?